# Re-load component to reflect new data (bryntum grid table)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, bryntum-grid

I have a bryntum grid table in my Vue component. I also have a bar chart where I can click on the bars and that triggers the byrntum grid table to update with new data. I need to somehow reload the entire bryntum grid component so that it can reflect the new data. I tried using a key and increment it to trigger a manual re-render of the component but it does not seem to work. How can I really reload a component to update the data?

Comment: Nobody here will be able to help you if you don't post the code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do not need to re-render the whole grid, it is enough if you re-load the grid store. There is a method for that (https://bryntum.com/docs/grid/api/Core/data/AjaxStore#function-load) that takes params so you can make the load dependent on what the user clicked.

You can also set new data in the code:

```
grid.store.data = [
    {id:1, name:'Hello'},
    {id:2, name:'World'},
    // etc
];
```

You can also ask you questions in their forum (https://www.bryntum.com/forum/) - the answers are quick and to the point.